# Loop a DataGrid

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I am usin compactframework c# vs 2005.

How can we loop a Datagrid in compactframework.I need to get a cell value

I am binding a datatable to datagrid. In datagrid I have a text box column. user will enter the value in this column. I need to get the value of this column of all rows.

Thanks

Comment: show code how you fill your datagrid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
myDGrid[rowIndex, colIndex];
```